# MySQL replace info of some rows of one column

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

First question here guys, but I consult here often! So I have a table for tires. The table has 4 kinds of tires in it sorted by SKUs. The SKUs are like this: KC1111, KW1111, KD1111, KB1111, and each code can span from KC1111 - KCnnnn. I need to update one column that is for tire weight, and for only one of the SKU prefixes (KC, KW, KD, KB, etc).

So I need to change the tire weight of all tires with the prefix KC from 20lbs to 0lbs. Here is what I have thus far:

`SELECT product_weight FROM jml_vm_product REGEXP('^KC') REPLACE('product_weight', '20.000', '0.0000');`

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Check out the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement, together with the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is the `Update` statement. In your case, you will have something like this :

```
UPDATE jml_vm_product 
SET product_weight = "20.000" 
WHERE your_SKUs_column LIKE 'KC%';
```